# Embedding Layer and Conv1D. DataFormat error

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I am building a model in Keras:

```
 model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Embedding(input_dim = unique_chars, output_dim = 512, name = "embd_1"),  input_shape=(None, 4, 1))) 
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')))
```

When i call fit method i get:

```
Attr 'data_format' of 'Conv2D' Op passed string 'NWC' not in: "NHWC", "NCHW".
```

Why is it happening? Do i need to a layer between Embedding and Conv1D?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What does your input shape mean?

Comment: It's currently incompatible with `Conv1D`. And your message says `Conv2D`. Are you sure this is your code?

Comment: Hi, Yes, it is my code. I dont know why the error message say conv2d :-/, because my layer is conv1d. Whitout embedding layer my model run, but it stucks in accuraccy 0.70, so i would like to try using an embedding layer
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'),  input_shape=(None, 4, 1)))

Comment: Because your input dimension is wrong. That's why I asked what it means. If you can eliminate the 1, then it will probably work.

Comment: Originally my input was a 8 length sequence. So, i followed that tutorial :https://monkcage.github.io/blog/ai/2019/01/28/time_series_forecast.html (Part 06: CNN-LSTM for Time Series Forecasting) and I reshaped my input

Comment: I changed my shape : [[1....8],[1...8]]--->  [   [[1...4],[2...8]],     [[1...4],[2...8]]    ]   . I would like to show my ideas in a better way, but english is hard to me